# Get left hand pane back in intellij Run window

Tags: intellij-idea

I upgraded my intellij version to 2016.3. After the update I am not able to see the left hand side pane when I run the tests. I tried clicking restore layout button but the layout stays the same. How to get the left hand side to show the tests back? Please help.

See the screen shot of how it looks right now below.
[image]

I am not able to see the left hand side pane.

[image]

Comment: can u pls screenshot wht u have now??

Comment: added it. See the first screen shot.